# how to give seperate color for cells which has uilocalnotification

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

i have set the `LocalNotification` like below and is working fine..
Now my problem is..if i open to see the notification,i want to give some color for the cells in `UITableView` for which i have got a notification..clearly..im doing bill reminder project and am setting the reminder for perfectly..now i want to give a separate color for the bill which got the notification..
please help me..the "ttt" is the last inserted row for the bills.

some statements

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:180];
localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",sometext];
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

id var = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: ttt];
[localNotification.userInfo setValue:var forKey:@"id"];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

some statements

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply the simple programming logic here.
Simply set some flag value for that particular remainder and while loading in the tableview cell, just check if that remainder loading in the cell has localnotification or not.
And change the color of your cell accordingly.

**MORE**: If you want to check whether that remainder has expired or not you can follow these following steps:

1 . While setting the remainder date , just store that date.

2 . When you are loading the cell:
compare the saved date for that particular remainder with the current date,

if (remainder date > current date)

set the green images or whatever to indicate remaider is not still expired

else

set the red images , indicating reamainder has already expired.

P.S: Use the logic